# regular expression and special variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

When using regular expressions in Ruby, what is the difference between
`$1`
and
`#{$1}`
?

NOTE:
markup =~ /(\d+)/

```
@a = $1  
s = "<div> ... '#{$1}' ... </div>"
my_function(par_1,#{$1},par_3)
```

**NOTE 2:**
I try again ...
regular expression: /(\d+)/
string: 123

The value of $1 is 123, correct ?
If I want to pass the value of the $1 variable to a function, shall I write

```
my_function(par_1,#{$1},par_3)
```

or

```
my_function(par_1,$1,par_3)
```

If I want to pass the address of the $1 variable to a function, shall I write

```
my_function(par_1,#{$1},par_3)
```

or

```
my_function(par_1,$1,par_3)
```

Last question: any reference where I could learn more ?

Comment: where you found it, source please . Good question, but not clear.

Comment: where is `"#{}"` here - `my_function(par_1,#{$1},par_3)` ?

Comment: I gave 3 examples. @a = value of $1 ? or string ?; in s, what is inserted ?; in my_fnction, what is the par_2, the value or the string or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` refers to a **numbered** capture group

`#{$1}` would be referring to a **named** capture group with the name "1", which is weird.
Normally it would be `#{$named}` or `#{r[:named]}`

Comment: could you give a concrete example ?